# How to evaluate accuracy on highly unbalanced data (using Naive Bayes model)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I found this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) on Kaggle containing transactions made by credit cards in September 2013 by European cardholders, over 2 days. The dataset is highly unbalanced, with frauds only taking 0.172% of all transactions.

I want to implement a (Gaussian) Naive Bayes classifier on this dataset to identify fraudulent transactions.

I've done the following already:

1. Load data into data frame
2. Split data into X and y
3. Standardize the data
4. Handle the unbalanced dataset with ADASYN
5. Build the Gaussian Naive Bayes model

Now, I want to evaluate the models:

```
from sklearn import metrics
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)
# Output: 0.95973427712704695

metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class)
# Output: 
# array([[68219,  2855],
#       [   12,   116]], dtype=int64)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_class, digits=4))
# Output:
#              precision    recall  f1-score   support
#
#           0     0.9998    0.9598    0.9794     71074
#           1     0.0390    0.9062    0.0749       128

#   micro avg     0.9597    0.9597    0.9597     71202
#   macro avg     0.5194    0.9330    0.5271     71202
#weighted avg     0.9981    0.9597    0.9778     71202
```

It was noted however in the dataset that:

"Given the class imbalance ratio, we recommend measuring the accuracy using the Area Under the Precision-Recall Curve (AUPRC). Confusion matrix accuracy is not meaningful for unbalanced classification."

So does this mean that I should measure accuracy with AUPRC even if I've already done ADASYN and oversampled the data?

I tried computing the accuracy for ROC_AUC (is this the same as AUPRC?) but received an error:

```
y_pred_prob = gaussian.predict_proba(X_test)
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob)
```

ValueError: bad input shape (71202, 2)

How do I properly calculate the accuracy for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the second class probability for each record. Try this!

```
y_pred_prob = np.array(gaussian.predict_proba(X_test))
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob[:,1])
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. Shouldn't I use AUPRC though instead of roc_auc_score? :o

Comment: Both can be used. ROC is the most commonly used one! It is also called as concordance metric of a model.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason why you can't use traditional accuracy or AUC curve is because you're **unbalanced**
Imagine you have 99 good transactions and 1 fraud and you want to detect fraud.

By prediction dumbly only good transactions (100 good transactions), you will have a 99% accuracy. Which can't be good because you missed the fraudulent transaction.

To evaluate **unbalanced dataset**, you should use metrics like **precision**, **recall** and **f1-score** for the given non-majority class.

The **recall** is the number of frauds you found correctly over the number of fraud in the whole dataset. E.g. You found 12 frauds with your algorithm and there are 100 frauds in the dataset, so your recall will be :

Recall = 12/100 => 12% / 0.12

The **precision** is the number of frauds you found correctly over the number of fraud you found. E.g. Your algorithm says that you found 12 frauds but among these 12 frauds, only 8 are real fraud, so your precision will be :

Precision =  8/12 => 66% / 0.66

The **F1-Score** is the harmonic mean between these two previous measures :

F1 = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

So here, F1 = (2 * 0.12 * 0.66)  / (0.12 + 0.66) = 0.20 => 20%

20% is not really good. At all.

In general, the objective is to **maximize** the F1 score, or sometimes the te precision or sometimes the recall depending of your needs.

But this is a **tradeoff**, when you improve one, the other lowers and vice versa.

For more information, you can take a look at wikipedia :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score

They also are available in sklearn ([sklearn.metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics)) :

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> precision_score(y_true, y_pred)  
0.22

from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')  
0.33

from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')  
0.26
```

An other metric to follow is the Precision-Recall Curve :

This is computing your precision vs recall for different thresholds.

```
import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(
...     y_true, y_scores)
>>> precision  
array([0.66666667, 0.5       , 1.        , 1.        ])
>>> recall
array([1. , 0.5, 0.5, 0. ])
>>> thresholds
array([0.35, 0.4 , 0.8 ])
```

[image]

How to read this ? Easy one !

This means that at 0.6 Recall, you have 0.9 Precision (Or the contrary)
And at 1 Recall, you have 0.6 Precision etc..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
y_pred_prob = gaussian.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Will return probability values for all the classes. Make sure you pass only one to the `roc_auc` function.

If you want the roc_auc function for the positive class, assuming it's 1(it usually is). Use this:

```
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob[:,1])
```

Check the docs [roc_auc_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) and [predict_proba](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.predict_proba)

Comment: According to the dataset, I should use AUPRC. Is roc_auc_score the same as this?

Comment: No, they're not the same.But that is a different question, I can point you to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338826/auprc-vs-auc-roc)

Comment: Thank you for this! But I'm still confused on what to implement for my code? Shouldn't I be using AUPRC instead of ROC AUC like you suggested?

Comment: Some implementations have an additional parameter eval_metric where you can specify a bunch of metrics like fscore,average-precision,roc_auc . I know xgboost for one has many. Maybe check out those models. As for GaussianNB I don&#39;t think you can add an eval_metric.

Answer (score 1):

In part of your question you asked whether area under the ROC curve is the same as AUPRC. They are not the same. A ROC curve is constructed using the true positive rate (recall) and the false positive rate. A PR curve is constructed using the true positive rate (recall) and the precision. AUPRC is a much better choice when your data set has many true negatives, because it doesn't use true negatives at all in its formulation.

Accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 score are "point metrics" that are calculated AFTER you apply a particular decision threshold to your classifier's predicted probabilities.

Area under the ROC curve ("AUC" or "AUROC") and area under the PR curve (AUPRC) are calculated BEFORE you apply a particular decision threshold. You can think of them as a summary of your classifier's performance across many decision thresholds. For more details, see [this article on AUROC](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2019/02/23/measuring-performance-auc-auroc/) and [this article on AUPRC](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2019/03/02/measuring-performance-auprc/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy: {0:.4f}".format(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_prob )))
```

To avoid printing many digits after decimal. (0:.4f)

Comment: Hi, but shouldn't we use AUPRC to evaluate metrics because our data is unbalanced? :)

Comment: Yup ! Of course you should ! Or precision, recall, F1-score.. etc